# nested v-for vuejs in a table

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have two set of data.

List of Time Durations

```
 timeDurations: [
   { 'duration': '02:30 AM - 03:00 AM' },
   { 'duration': '03:00 AM - 03:30 AM' },
   { 'duration': '03:30 AM - 04:00 AM' },
   { 'duration': '04:00 AM - 04:30 AM' },
   { 'duration': '04:30 AM - 05:00 AM' },
   { 'duration': '05:00 AM - 05:30 AM' },
   { 'duration': '05:30 AM - 06:00 AM' }
 ];
```

List of Bus assigned to that specific duration

```
 assignedBus: [
   { 'duration': '03:00 AM - 03:30 AM', 'bus': 'Bus1' },
   { 'duration': '04:00 AM - 04:30 AM', 'bus': 'Bus2' },
   { 'duration': '05:00 AM - 05:30 AM', 'bus': 'Bus3' }
 ];
```

I am using table to display that List of Time Durations using vue js

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hovered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Time Duration</th>
        <th>Bus</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="time in timeDurations">
        <td>{{time.duration}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Assign Bus</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

But actually, I want to display the time durations and corresponding button based on `assignedBus` data

the values in the table must be like this

```
|     Time Durations     |     Action    |
|   02:30 AM - 03:00 AM  |   Assign Bus  |
|   03:00 AM - 03:30 AM  |    View Bus   |
|   03:30 AM - 04:00 AM  |   Assign Bus  |
|   04:00 AM - 04:30 AM  |    View Bus   |
|   04:30 AM - 05:00 AM  |   Assign Bus  |
|   05:00 AM - 05:30 AM  |    View Bus   |
|   05:30 AM - 06:00 AM  |   Assign Bus  |
```

So, if `timeDurations` has matching data in `assignedBus` the button must be `View Bus` else `Assign Bus`

here's my fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/31/

please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the for loop in the for loop. Check my [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/s23guabq/):

```
hasAssignedBus(duration) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.assignedBus.length; i++) {
      if(this.assignedBus[i].duration == duration) {
        return true;
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```

cheers

Comment: yay!! Thank you very much that's what i want. Yes, it is because of the nested for loop. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your data structures a bit. I suggest you this approach:

```
timeDurations: [
    '02:30 AM - 03:00 AM',
    '03:00 AM - 03:30 AM',
    '03:30 AM - 04:00 AM',
    '04:00 AM - 04:30 AM',
    '04:30 AM - 05:00 AM',
    '05:00 AM - 05:30 AM',
    '05:30 AM - 06:00 AM'
],
assignedBus: {
    '03:00 AM - 03:30 AM': 'Bus1',
    '04:00 AM - 04:30 AM': 'Bus1',
    '05:00 AM - 05:30 AM': 'Bus1'
}
```

And then your markup can be simplified as well:

```
<template v-for="time in timeDurations">
  <tr>
    <td>{{time}}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">
        {{ assignedBus[time]  ? "View Bus" : "Assign Bus" }}
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

If you want to use your format, use this:

```
methods: {
  checkBus(duration) {
    return this.assignedBus.find(function(info) {
        return info.duration === duration
      });
    }
 }
```

And template:

```
<template v-for="time in timeDurations">
  <tr v-if="hasAssignedBus(time.duration)">
    <td>{{time.duration}}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-primary">
      View Bus
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-else>
     <td>{{time.duration}}</td>
     <td><button class="btn btn-primary">
       Assign Bus
      </button></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: But what if I used my data structure format, how can i do it like yours?, because those data are from database